# Getting weird O/P while trying to print struct values in C

Tags: struct, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct info
{
        int id;
        char name[20];
};

int main()
{
        struct info p;
        struct info *ptr;

        ptr = &p;


        (*ptr).id = 20;
        strcpy((*ptr).name, "Delluh");


        printf("\n %u %u %u\n\n",*ptr,ptr->id,ptr->name);



        return 0;

}
```

The last printf statement give me an output of '20 1819043140 26741' of which 20 is the correct value and the remaining 2 values are some garbage values. However on removing the * from ptr, I get the correct output of an address value, 20 and then another address value. Can anyone please tell me why putting the * in front of ptr causes the other two values to get messed up?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be more corrent if you would use this

```
printf("\n %p %i %s\n\n",ptr,ptr->id,ptr->name);
```

You are using %u(unsigned integer) in printf for all parameters but you are passing a pointer, and integer and a string parameter I think that is the problem you are having. 
You should have a look at [printf documentation](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/printf.html) about what the %s,%u,%i etc. parameters mean.

Comment: Yes, I know that that is the correct way to do it, but I was just wondering why putting a * causes the other 2 values to become wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because with the `*` there, you're dereferencing the struct and passing the whole thing in—id and name&mdash.

Printf uses varargs, which basically just means you can pass in as many arguments of whatever type you want, but you it also means that the compiler won't do any automatic type conversion or checking for you (because it doesn't know what types to expect). So the arguments you pass in just end up as a sequence of bytes on the stack, and the format string tells printf how to interpret that string of bytes. Among other things, it tells it how many bytes to skip over to get to the next argument.

So you wanted the `ptr->id` the first argument, which is only 4 bytes. But you actually passed all 24 bytes of the struct as the argument. So after printf finished printing the first 4 bytes as an unsigned int, it was ready to print the next argument, but was still stuck at the beginning of the name field. If you look, the "garbage" value it printed is 0x6C6C6544, which are 4 ASCII characters "lleD", which is your string, interpreted as a little-endian integer.

In general, you can probably get away with pulling the first field out of struct just by dereferencing the pointer (the pointer points to both the struct and its first field), but only if the compiler knows that's what you're trying to do based on the type. For instance, this will probably works:

```
int id = *ptr;
```

Technically, that at least could workd, because the compiler knows what type you're actually trying to get to. Realistically, the compiler will probably issue an error or warning, and you'll need to do some casting.